# Complex Metric Space

Tags: general-topology, complex-numbers, metric-spaces

Consider the complex metric space $\mathbb{C}$ with the standard metric, let $x\in \mathbb{C}$. Show that if $a\in B(x,r)$ then there exists a non-zero h$\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $a+h \in B(x,r)$

May I have hints on how to prove this?

Comment: Try using the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Gae.S. sorry, I forgot to say non-zero h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take $h=\frac12\bigl(r-\lvert x-a\rvert\bigr)$. That will work since, by the triangle inequality,$$B\bigl(a,r-\lvert x-a\rvert\bigr)\subset B(x,r).$$